# Can't connect multiple UIButtons to my IBAction

Tags: ios, ibaction

I'm working through an AutoLayout tutorial and trying to connect two `UIButtons` to a single `@IBAction` I can only get one connected.

I have three `UIButtons` seen below. I want to connect the Like and Wink buttons to `@IBAction fund buttonTapped(sender:).

[image]

The instructor in the video creates the `@IBAction` with the usual Ctrl-drag from the Like button to the `UIViewController` with no problem. He then Ctrl-drags from the Wink button to that `@IBAction` and connects it with no problem. But when I try to do exactly the same thing, Xcode won't give me the choice to connect the Wink button to that action. I connect the Like button first, but then when I try to connect the Wink button, it will only give me the option to create a new `@IBAction` above, below, or inside it.

I've looked here on SO and found answers like the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870701/how-to-use-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons-in-swift) but the answers are simply saying to do what I'm trying to do and it isn't working. I've tried selecting both buttons and then creating the `@IBAction` with no luck. I've tried selecting both of them in the view hierarchy and still no luck.

This is such a simple thing that I feel like I've been able to do before. Has something changed in Xcode (I'm using 7.3.1), am I missing something obvious, am I doing something wrong, or am I maybe losing my mind?

EDIT #1
Strangely, right after I Ctrl-drag from the Like button to by `UIViewController` and create the `@IBAction`, here's what the Connections look like:

[image]

But if I then click away and come immediately back to the Connections without doing anything else, it looks like this:

[image]

This blows my mind because it is defined in my `UIViewController` - I just created it.

Comment: Isn't the button, that refuses to connect, connected to another IBAction, or isn't it already connected? What does the Connections Inspector show while having such button selected in storyboard? http://pasteboard.co/gzSA8ICPf.png

Comment: Well, have you tried restaritng Xcode? It may sound stupid, but Xcode has a tendency to stuck sometimes.

Comment: The other button (Wink) isn't connected to anything when I'm trying to do this. I added screenshot of the Connections Inspector above. Thanks.

Comment: @Losiowaty - actually it doesn't sound stupid at all. I should have thought it myself. Unfortunately, I tried it now and it didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: @Losiowaty, your suggestion made me think that there could be a problem with the starter project I downloaded from the tutorial site. So, I just took 60 seconds to create it from scratch myself and guess what, problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on button and then drag from `touch up inside` to your `IBAction`

Comment: No joy, Kubba. it will let me create a new one but it won't let me connect to the existing one. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the starter project I downloaded from the tutorial site had some kind of problem that was causing this. I just created it from scratch myself and the problem went away. I can easily connect both buttons to that single action doing it any of the several ways I was trying. Thanks for the suggestions, especially to @Losiowaty who triggered my brain to try this.