# Button opacity / alpha setting

Tags: swift

I want to change the alpha when the user pressed the button. I have used the below code and it works. 
However, I am having to write this line of code for every button I connect to the assistance.

Is there any way that I can create a method/class/function to enable all buttons to have this function?

```
@IBAction func sundayButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.alpha = 0.5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {sender.alpha = 1.0

    }
}
```

Comment: How about setting/linking this IBAction to your other buttons as well? Thus each button tap will trigger `sundayButton` action. Also you can check which button is clicked via sender which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870701/how-to-use-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write extention on Button and call that on every button

```swift
extension UIButton {
    func setAlpha() {
        self.alpha = 0.5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

call it this way:

```
myButton.setAlpha()
```

Comment: You can add parameters as well if you need:
`func setAlpha(from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat) { ... }`