# Check for condition befor executing button selector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have multiple buttons with different functions, now these buttons should check for a condition befor executing the actual functionality, I don't won't to change all buttons functions like the following:

```
@objc func btnAction(sender: UIButton) {
  if condition {
    runSomthing()
    return
  } else {
    run the actual btn action
  }
}
```

I need to extract this to a superclass that accomplishes what I looking for without changing the current button actions

Is there a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to link all the buttons to the same IBAction and perform corresponding button functionalities using the button tag value. This prevents the condition checking in each IBAction.

```
  guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
    return
    }
    
    if condition {
    runSomthing()
    return
    } else {
    switch button.tag {
    case 1:
    Perform operation A
    case 2:
    Perform operation B
    case 3:
    Perform operation C
    default:
    print("None")
    return
    }
    }
```

Enums can also be used instead of tag value for better identification. I referred [How to use one IBAction for multiple buttons in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870701/how-to-use-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons-in-swift)